# How can i use @Retryable(label="...") for logging or monitoring purposes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have simple retryable method annotated with

```
@Retryable(label = "myLabel")
```

According to documentation, it should be

> A unique label for statistics reporting

Is this label accessible inside RetryListener? How can i use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The label is available in the `RetryContext.NAME` attribute in the context.

```
@Component
class Foo {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

    @Retryable(label = "myLabel")
    public void retriable() {
        log.info("Here with label: " + RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getAttribute(RetryContext.NAME));
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Exception e) {
        log.info("Recovered");
    }

}
```

The context is available in the listener methods.

There's a [new feature in 1.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/commit/b599c234043c90f0b40885f6e7aaf26bc8d5c4d8).

1.3 is not released yet but there is a snapshot 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in the spring snapshots repo https://repo.spring.io/snapshot.

This also gives you access to the method invocation.

```java
@Component
class MyRetryListener extends MethodInvocationRetryListenerSupport {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRetryListener.class);

    @Override
    protected <T, E extends Throwable> boolean doOpen(RetryContext context,
            MethodInvocationRetryCallback<T, E> callback) {

        log.info("Invocation of method: " + callback.getInvocation().getMethod().toGenericString()
                + " with label: " + callback.getLabel());
        return super.doOpen(context, callback);
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

    @Retryable(label = "myLabel")
    public void retriable() {
        log.info("Here");
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Exception e) {
        log.info("Recovered");
    }

}
```

Comment: Correction there's a simpler approach; the label is in the retry context; edited.

Comment: Thanx. Too bad label property is apparently also exclusive with interceptor (although i dont see any good reason for it - i think label should work with interceptor). For now, i will parse method name from RetryContext.NAME (which has default value like 'public void ... (...)', even when label is not set)

Comment: ?? All other properties are ignored when using `interceptor` - per the javadocs. You can set the label on the interceptor instead `StatelessRetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless().label("myLabel").build();`.

Comment: Yes, i know. But what i find useful about interceptor is that i can easily reuse complex retry configuration for multiple @Retryable methods and having single label for all of them is useless. Anyway, once 1.3 is released i will solve it with MethodInvocationRetryCallback